# Serving locally a webapp

Tags: javascript, python, server

I'm developing an html web page which will visualize data. The intention is that this web page works only on one computer, so I don't want it to be online. Just off line. The web uses only Js, css and html. It is very simple and is not using any database, the data is loaded through D3js XMLHttpRequest. Up to now it is working with a local python server for development, through python -m SimpleHTTPServer. Eventually I will want to launch it easyer. Is it possible to pack the whole thing in a launchable app? Do you recommend some tools to do it or some things to read? What about the server part? Is it possible to launch a "SimpleHTTPServer" kind of thing without the console? Or maybe just one command which launches the server plus the web?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: NWJS, Element, cordova, adobe AIR, HTA, etc

Comment: what operating system do you use?

Comment: I'm using Mac OS X, but I don't know the OS of the final destination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

Save and compile following file in your folder.Double click on .pyc file to run it.

```
import SocketServer
import SimpleHTTPServer
import webbrowser

PORT = 8000

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) 
print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
webbrowser.open(<yourip:PORT>)
```

This should work on all platforms

Put the following into a text file and save it with extension .bat

```
cd yourfolder
python -m SimpleHTTPServer port
C:\>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "yourip:port" --new-window
```

This should work fine in windows

For Mac

```
cd yourfolder
python -m SimpleHTTPServer port
open -a "Google Chrome" --args --kiosk http://google.com
```

and save with extension .command

Comment: Thanks. Is it something like that for Mac OS X or Linux? I don´t know the OS of the final destination and I would like to cover most of the possibilities.

Comment: When you're not sure about the destination OS, you might not be sure about the browser either. If you're going down this path you should check if there is a way to retrieve the OS default browser and create a `.bat` script for Windows, and a `.sh` for Linux / OSX.

Comment: Note that `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` only works if `python` resolves to Python 2.7. For Python 3.x, use `python -m http.server` instead.

Comment: @moaimx see updated answer for a cross platform solution.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what you are trying to achieve from reading the question. but from what i understand is that you'd like to be able to launch your application and serve it on the web when done.
you could use heroku!(www.heroku.com), same way you are hosting the application on your local, you simply make a Procfile, and in that file you put in the command that you'd normally run on your local, and push to Heroku.

Comment: I don't want to use the web, I just want to launch it locally.

Comment: "Do you recommend some tools to do it or some things to read? What about the server part? Is it possible to launch a "SimpleHTTPServer" kind of thing without the console? Or maybe just one command which launches the server plus the web?"

Ans: Look into Express the Node.js framework, the command is as simple as;
node <entryfilename>